# Windows 7 - Taskbar - Pin or Unpin Program Links

Tags: winapi, windows-7

As in title, is there any Win32 API to do that?

Comment: Isn't pinning or unpinning meant to be done by users? Why should a program do it for them?

Comment: My customer needs our installer to pin/unpin the application on Taskbar by default. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that this functionality, like Pin to Start Menu in XP/Vista, is *deliberately* not exposed precisely so that programs cannot override the *user's* decision as to whether a program merits precious taskbar space.  Otherwise every spammy program would consider itself SO GOSH-DARNED IMPORTANT that it would pin itself to the taskbar regardless of the user's consent.  See numerous Raymond Chen articles passim.

Comment: If you have a specific customer who wants to pin/unpin your app on its users' taskbars, I'd look for a Group Policy setting rather than an API.  (The design decision being "who do we trust to decide whether Program X goes on the taskbar: the sysadmin, or Program X?")  Don't know whether there is such a setting, but you could try asking on serverfault.com.

Comment: @Yigang Wu: is your customer the Government? If not, then I hope they have a very good reason for overriding the user's preferences.

Comment: I understand the dangers of having such an API, but it would be useful in creating a program that switches the taskbar between user-created contexts such as "development", "personal", and "gaming". Depending on why I'm using my computer, I want a different set of applications visible on the taskbar.

Comment: It is typical that people answer here what they BELIEVE if they don't KNOW (like itowlson) and then other people who don't know either vote up this wrong comment. The correct answer was given below by Ciantic. "The user's decision..." This is nonsense. If I write an installer that asks my user if he wants a shortcut in the taskbar it IS the user's decision that my installer writes a link to the taskbar. Why should Miscrosoft forbid this? There are many users without computer kowledge who don't find a program if it is not in the taskbar even since Windows 8 where the startmenu is a bad joke.

Answer (score 16):

Don't do this.

I'm 99% sure there isn't an official API for it, for exactly the same reason that there wasn't [programmatic access to the old Start Menu's pin list](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx).

In short, most users don't want programs putting junk in **their** favorites, quick launch, taskbar, etc. so Windows doesn't support you doing as such.

Comment: Kevin's answer is the right one :).  Just resist the pressure from your customer.

Comment: Wow... when Larry Osterman agrees with an answer, it's probably the right one :)

Comment: There are valid reasons, e.g. I'm using multiple desktops (opensource) VirtuaWin, and I want to pin different programs to different desktops. I need to find API for this to implement it.

Comment: Kevin, you are 99% WRONG! It is typical that people answer here what they BELIEVE if they don't KNOW and then others who don't know either vote up this wrong answer. The code posted by Ciantic shows that you are wrong. "Users don't want..." This is nonsense. If I write an installer that asks my user if he wants a shortcut in the taskbar it IS the user's decision that my installer writes a link to the taskbar. Why should Miscrosoft forbid this? There are many users with no computer kowledge who dont find a program if its not in the taskbar even since Windows 8 where the startmenu is a bad joke.

Comment: Also a programmers view is not the only one to be considered. As a sysadmin it is super annoying to not have the control over this only point in the system. And please stop the "users don't want" arguments... An admin (and most programmers too) has the rights to completely cripple the user in 99 out of 100 aspects of windows. To not give that power in that last one is just plain lazy of microsoft. No one benefits from that. And hey look at Windows 10 which comes with amazing prepinned MS applications.... where is the user choice now?

Answer (score 7):

I'm trying to implement a [VirtuaWin (opensource virtual desktop software)](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net) plugin that allows me to pin different buttons to different virtual desktops. Completely valid reason to use this.

Found the way to pin/unpin it already:

Following code snippet is taken from [Chromium shortcut.cc file](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/base/win/shortcut.cc&l=308), nearly unchanged, see also the [`ShellExecute` function at the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
bool TaskbarPinShortcutLink(const wchar_t* shortcut) {
  int result = reinterpret_cast<int>(ShellExecute(NULL, L"taskbarpin", shortcut,
      NULL, NULL, 0));
  return result > 32;
}

bool TaskbarUnpinShortcutLink(const wchar_t* shortcut) {
  int result = reinterpret_cast<int>(ShellExecute(NULL, L"taskbarunpin",
      shortcut, NULL, NULL, 0));
  return result > 32;
}    
// Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.
```

Seems pretty straightforward if you know the shortcut. For me though this is not sufficient, I also need to iterate over *existing* buttons and unpin and repin them on different desktops.

Comment: GREAT! This works perfectly. It seems to be an undocumented feature. The MSDN does not tell us about the operation "taskbarpin". You forgot to mention that "shortcut" in your code must be the path to an already existing shortcut anywhere on disk. ShellExecute does not create a new shortcut. It just copies an existing shortcut to the folder "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" and makes the shortcut visible in the taskbar. IMPORTANT: If you only copy a shortcut to this folder it will NOT appear in the taskbar.

Comment: Note that ShellExecute("taskbarpin") returns error 31 if the icon is already beeing displayed in the taskbar. In this case the function does NOT copy the LNK file to the folder "...User Pinned\TaskBar".

Comment: Another important point is that ShellExecute("taskbarunpin")  fails with error 5 if the file to which the shortcut is pointing does not exist. (It seems to be a bug.) This means: if you see a shortcut in the taskbar, and the corresponding LNK file exists, but the destination of the LNK does not exist, then it becomes impossible to remove the taskbar shortcut. So if you write an uninstaller you must first unpin your application and then delete the application itself.

Comment: This works, but be aware that Microsoft removed support for it in Windows 10.  And there was no "pin to taskbar" feature before 7.  Therefore it only works on 7 and 8, which I have confirmed by testing directly.

Comment: This is further confirmed in a [Chromium code comment](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:base/win/shortcut.cc;l=359?q=shortcut.cc&ss=chromium&originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F): `"Pin to taskbar" stopped being supported in Windows 10.`

Answer (score 2):

In the comments of a [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/taskbarpinutility.aspx?msg=3273224) it says all you have to do is create a symbolic link in the folder "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar".

But it appears to generally be unsociable practice, as the other comments here have noted.

Comment: Incidentally, recent versions of Chrome seem to do this both when you install it and the first time it launches.

Answer (score 2):

You can pin/unpin apps via Windows Shell verbs:
http://blogs.technet.com/deploymentguys/archive/2009/04/08/pin-items-to-the-start-menu-or-windows-7-taskbar-via-script.aspx

For API, there is a script-friendly COM library for working with the Shell:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776890%28VS.85%29.aspx

Here is an example written in JScript:

```
// Warning: untested and probably needs correction
var appFolder = "FOLDER CONTAINING THE APP/SHORTCUT";
var appToPin = "FILENAME OF APP/SHORTCUT";
var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var folder = shell.NameSpace(appFolder);
var folderItem = folder.ParseName(appToPin);
var itemVerbs = folderItem.Verbs;
for(var i = 0; i < itemVerbs.Count; i++)
{
    // You have to find the verb by name,
    //  so if you want to support multiple cultures,
    //  you have to match against the verb text for each culture.
    if(itemVerbs[i].name.Replace(/&/, "") == "Pin to Start Menu")
    {
        itemVerbs[i].DoIt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to put some links on the info as microsoft now offer an official documentation on "[Taskbar Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460%28VS.85%29.aspx)" :

> A small set of applications are pinned
>   by default for new installations.
>   Other than these, only the user can
>   pin further applications; **programmatic
>   pinning by an application is not
>   permitted.**

So *Kevin Montrose* answer is the correct one : DON'T.

Comment: The answer from Kevin is definitely WRONG. See my comment there.

Answer (score 2):

It works, but not for all OS, e.g. Windows 10:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

    private static void PinUnpinTaskBar(string filePath, bool pin)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath + " not exists!");

        int MAX_PATH = 255;
        var actionIndex = pin ? 5386 : 5387; // 5386 is the DLL index for"Pin to Tas&kbar", ref. http://www.win7dll.info/shell32_dll.html
        StringBuilder szPinToStartLocalized = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
        IntPtr hShell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll");
        LoadString(hShell32, (uint)actionIndex, szPinToStartLocalized, MAX_PATH);
        string localizedVerb = szPinToStartLocalized.ToString();

        // create the shell application object
        dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));

        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        dynamic directory = shellApplication.NameSpace(path);
        dynamic link = directory.ParseName(fileName);

        dynamic verbs = link.Verbs();
        for (int i = 0; i < verbs.Count(); i++)
        {
            dynamic verb = verbs.Item(i);

            if ((pin && verb.Name.Equals(localizedVerb)) || (!pin && verb.Name.Contains(localizedVerb)))
            {
                verb.DoIt();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found there is no offical API to do that, but someone has do it through VBScript.
http://blog.ananthonline.net/?p=37
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this folder contains shortcut of pinned application

C:\Users\Your-User-Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

Comment: Ummm... I just tried pinning an item to the taskbar and this folder wasn't created.  Are you sure that it works for Windows 7?

Comment: @Larry This folder works only for detecting whether a program is pinned or not. Adding new shortcuts to it won't add pinned items to the taskbar.

Comment: If you would ever have tried to copy a shortcut to that folder you would have seen that it does NOT appear in the taskbar. The pure existence of the file is not enough. See the correct answer from Ciantic.