# How to add taskbar shortcut during msi install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

VisualStudio 2010 setup project for winforms: I have a customer request to add a shortcut icon to the taskbar during install. I am not immediately seeing how to do this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134556/taskbar-icon-for-all-users

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=taskbar+shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a desktop shortcut, a start menu item and a program folder shortcut. I have not found a way to create a shortcut on the Task bar, you could just ask them to drag and drop the shortcut from the desktop.