# Windows8 internet explorer shortcut

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, shortcut, taskbar

I tried to experiment with create/update shortcuts for Windows 8 TaskBar.
I started playing with *Internet Explorer.lnk*

`C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Internet Explorer.lnk`

And found next thing:
In spite of I **changed target** for the link, clicking to link starts **Internet Explorer** (and link target is the first argument for IE).

I checked the link's target property and found that it is really changed to my target (I choose "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")

Than I analyzed link with "Windows Link (Shortcut) File Explorer"
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521802/Windows-Link-Shortcut-File-Explorer

and found hidden **Name** Parameter (see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Je3R.png)

`@ "%windir%\System32\ie4uinit.exe",-7324`

Question is:

**what is it? How I can create/change the same "hidden": link?**


I didn't find some methods in IShellLink interface.

Thanks,

Comment: ie4uinit is probably the comment/description.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change shortcuts in windows 8, you will have to touch registry values found in

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband

But from experience, its a big headache.

Instead, Just use ShellExecute with the operations **taskbarpin** and **taskbarunpin** in the following way:

```
bool TaskbarPinShortcutLink(const wchar_t* shortcut) {
  int result = reinterpret_cast<int>(ShellExecute(NULL, L"taskbarpin", shortcut,
      NULL, NULL, 0));
  return result > 32;
}

bool TaskbarUnpinShortcutLink(const wchar_t* shortcut) {
  int result = reinterpret_cast<int>(ShellExecute(NULL, L"taskbarunpin",
      shortcut, NULL, NULL, 0));
  return result > 32;
}
```

shortcut could be Internet Explorer found in the desktop directory, or any other lnk file.

Also check out [Windows 7 - Taskbar - Pin or Unpin Program Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968137/windows-7-taskbar-pin-or-unpin-program-links) for more info.